# How to save text fields in a custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, tableview, textfield

Question is in the title ^^. How do you go about saving say 2 textFields in a custom tableView cell. Pretend the reuse identifier doesn't exist (however is someone could show me how to get around that then that would be awesome). Thanks for anyone that can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What you mean by 'saving' textField? Did you mean storing text from it? Or inserting into cell? Please add more information or post a screenshot, as this question looks not properly asked. Adding your code would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom UITableViewCell class you can add textfields from an array of textfields.

ie, in the viewDidLoad you can insert two textfields of tag 110 and 111 in an array.

```
     -(void)viewDidLoad
      {
         arryTextfields = [NSMUtableArray alloc]init];
         for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
         {
            UITextField * textField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
            NSMutableDictionary * dic =[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]
            [dic setObject:textField forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"11%d",i]];
            [arryTextfields addObject:dic];
            [textField release];
            [dic release];
          }
       }
```

In your tableview delegate "cellForRowAtIndexPath".

```
              - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
               static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
               YourCustomTableviewCell * cell = [[YourCustomTableviewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

               UITextField * textfield1 = [[cell.arryTextfields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"110"];

                UITextField * textfield2 = [[cell.arryTextfields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"111"];


             return cell;
            }
```

Comment: So I have this code implemented now but I need to know how I can save the textfields so that each cell's textfields will display different information

Comment: Why you want to save the text fields.Yo can save the value of each textfield in a dictionary with unique key for a textfield.